# CMake script and directory structure for multiple nested projects and libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to know what is the best way to make directory structure for multiple dependent c++ projects which is built using cmake and how cmake script should look like in this case. (I do it in linux with gcc if it is important.)

I have multiple independent projects `A`, `B`. Also I have multiple libraries `X`, `Y`.

There are no problem when those libraries is made by other developers. I can use existing `FindX.cmake` or write own to track them.

The problem arises when `X`, `Y` are my own libraries. Let `A` depends on `X` and `Y`, project `B` depends on `Y`. Furthermore, let `Y` depends on `X` (because I reuse some common, not task related code). However I assume that there can be more libraries, projects, and greater depth of their nesting. The second assumption is that libraries (`X` for example) can provide not only libraries like *.so, but also can provide some executables (not only for testing).

When I rebuild my project I want to rebuild all dependencies, because I can make modifications in projects and libraries simultaneously. Moreover, I want to separate libraries from each other and create one directory `code` with all my projects, which will contain 4 subdirs: `~/code/A`, `~/code/B`, `~/code/X`, `~/code/Y`. Every project will have own tests and will be pushed in separate code repositories.

The best links I found about building proper directory structure is [this](https://github.com/toeb/moderncmake) and [this](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/). However authors suggest to create nested directory structure, which seems difficult to do in my example, because if I do this way, I will end up with directory structure like this:

```
A/X
A/Y/X
B/Y/X
```

which I can get by using symlinks. But then in my separate directory with compiled binaries for each project (`A/build`, `B/build`, `X/build`, `Y/build`) I will have copy of libraries and executables from different libraries. If I call `make install` for all builds, those copies will create mess due to duplication of binaries and libraries.

**UPDATE (SOLUTION):**

The answer happens to be rather simple, I found it after few days of experimenting with cmake and reading documentation.

1. **Libray**. Add next two lines:

   ```
   export(PACKAGE <pkgName>)
   export(TARGETS <libTarget> FILE <pkgName>Config.cmake)
   ```

   - First line will create entry in `~/.cmake/packages/` which will tell where build dir of library is situated. Cmake invocations in other projects start search from that path.
   - Second line will create `Find<pkgName>.cmake` in build directory.
2. **Executable**. Add next lines:

   ```
   find_package(<pkgName> QUIET)

   if(${<pkgName>_FOUND})
     message(STATUS "Found <pkgName>.")
   else(${<pkgName>_FOUND})
     message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not locate <pkgName>!")
   endif(${<pkgName>_FOUND})
   ```

   So, if library wasn't built we will see error message, otherwise we will be able to use target `<libTarget>`.

Of course, building executable don't trigger rebuilding library if some changes in library sources are made. To overcome this problem I wrote bash script to call `make` firstly in library, and next in executable build dir.

P. S. If you know better solution, I am still waiting for it.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally use is something like this

```
~/my_project
~/my_project/src
~/my_project/src/A
~/my_project/src/B
~/my_project/src/X
~/my_project/src/Y
```

The main `CMakeLists.txt` uses `add_subdirectory` to add the `src` directory. The `src/CMakeLists.txt` in turn uses `add_subdirectory` to add `A`, `B`, `X` and `Y`.

With properly setup dependencies in the `CMakeLists.txt` files, CMake will handle the dependencies correctly, and rebuild everything needed (so if you make a change in `X` then `Y`, `A` and `B` should be rebuilt correctly).

Comment: If A and B absolutely independent and I push them in different online repositories, where ~/my_project/CMakeLists.txt, ~/my_project/src/CMakeLists.txt should go?

Comment: @BhavinChirag If `A` and `B` are truly independent, then my scheme won't work, as it sees `A` and `B` as part of a package, or sub-projects. My recommendation in this case is to make `X` and `Y` independent as well, creating your own `FindX.cmake` and `FindY.cmake` files that can be used, and build the libraries independently, and then build and install each library separately and in the right order.